# Preserving whether or not a user has turned on closed captioning in Wistia

Tags: wistia

I would like to preserve the closed caption on or off state (and language) a user has selected for Wistia videos. Is there a JavaScript event that can be used to capture a change in the player's closed captioning status? If not, what is the preferred solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing an event handler that would capture any click event on the page. I first check to see if the inner text is that of one of the available languages in the CC menu. Then, just for safety, I ensure that it's a child of the <div> that has a .w-captions-menu class.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var innerText = e.target.innerText;
    if(innerText == 'English' || innerText == 'Off'){
        if($(e.target).parents('.w-captions-menu').length){
            // Respond to event here
        }
    }
});
```

It was necessary to write a generic event handler because the Wistia elements don't exist when the page loads. The menu items themselves don't exist until you click the CC button on the player. So an event handler like the following wouldn't work since the element it's selecting don't exist yet:

```
$('.w-caption-menu button').click(function(){
   // Respond to event
});
```